# Selectively reading from CSV to MySQL

Tags: mysql, csv, architecture

This is a two part question.

- The first is what architecture should I use for the following issue?
- And the second is the how i.e. what commands I should use?

I have some log files I want to read into a database.  The log files contain fields that are unnecessary (because they can be calculated from other fields).

**Approach 1:** Should I parse each line of the log file and insert it into the database?
**Con:** The log entries have to be unique, so I need to first do a SELECT, check if the LogItemID exists, and then INSERT if it doesn’t.  This seems to be a high overhead activity and at some point this will be done on an hourly basis.

**Approach 2:** Or do I use LOAD DATA INFILE (can I even use that in PHP?) and just load the log file into a temporary table, then move the records into the permanent table?
**Con:** Even in this method though, I will still have to go through the cycle of SELECT, then INSERT.

**Approach 3:** Or is there a better way?  Is there a command to bulk copy records from one table to another with selected fields?  Will REPLACE INTO .... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE work (I don't want to UPDATE if the item exists, just ignore) as long as LogItemID is set to UNIQUE ? Either way, I need to throw the extraneous fields out.  Which of these approaches is better?  Not just easier, but from the standpoint of writing good, scalable code?

P.S. Unrelated, but part of the Architecture issue here is this...
If I have StartTime, EndTime and Interval (EndTime-StartTime), which should I keep - the first two or Interval? And Why?

Edit: To clarify why I did not want to store all three fields - the issue is of course normalization and therefore not good practice. For audit reasons, perhaps I'll store them.  Perhaps in another table?
TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LOAD DATA INFILE` is going to be a lot faster than running individual inserts.

You could load to a separate, temporary table, and then run an `INSERT ... SELECT` from the temporary table into your actual store. But it's not clear why you would need to do that. To "skip" some fields in the CSV, just assign those to dummy user-defined variables. There's no need to load those fields into the temporary table.

I'd define a `UNIQUE` key (constraint) and just use `INSERT IGNORE`; that will be a lot faster than running a separate `SELECT`, and faster than a `REPLACE`. (If your requirement is that you don't have any need to update the existing row, you just want to "ignore" the new row.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'my.csv'
IGNORE
INTO TABLE mytable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
( mycol
, @dummy2
, @dummy3
, @mm_dd_yyyy
, somecol 
)
SET mydatecol = STR_TO_DATE(@mm_dd_yyyy,'%m-%d-%Y')
```

If you have `start`, `end` and `duration`, go ahead and store all three. There's redundancy there, the main issues are performance and update anomalies. (If you update `end`, should you also update `duration`?) If I don't have a need to do updates, I'd just store all three. I could calculate `duration` from `start_time` and `end_time`, but having the column stored would allow me to add an index, and get better performance on queries looking for durations less than 10 minutes, or whatever. Absent the column, I'd be forced to evaluate an expression for every row in the table, and that gets expensive on large sets.

Answer (score 1):

You could use perl to parse out a subset of the csv fields you want to load, then use the command 'uniq' to remove duplicates, then use LOAD DATA INFILE to load the result.

Typically loading data into a temporary table, then traversing is slower than preprocessing the data ahead of time. As for the LogItemID, if you set it to unique the inserts should fail when you load subsequent matching lines.

When it comes to deciding to store StartTime+Interval (more typically called Duration) or StartTime and EndTime, it really depends on how you plan on using the resulting database table. If you store the duration and are constantly computing the end time it might be better to just store the start/end. If you believe the duration will be commonly used, store it. Depending on how big the database you might decide to just store all three, one more field may not add much overhead.